# Using threads to run a method that is not part of the transaction?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

i have a case where at my JAVA application, inside a transaction i want to call another service (JMS, WebService, SMS gate way, ...etc), i don't want to depend on the result of the call (Success, Fail, Exception thrown, ... etc), so if it fails somehow it won't affect my transaction completion,

what is the best approach to use this, am using Spring framework,

also i want to ask if i used threads for handling this, but my deployment will be on clusters(i.e different nodes with separate JVMs), what's the best way for handling (Lock, synchronization),

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd schedule this in a [quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) job.

Comment: also take in consideration that, i want to run this method as soon as i call it

Comment: I'd simply put the job in a quartz queue for asynchronous execution. Spring has good integration with quartz. Of course if you aren't already using quartz in your application it may be an overkill to introduce it just for this use case.

Comment: am using quartz already, but what am not sure of, if using it will grantee at some point that the job will be started when calling it , so making the job running within small period will solve this?

Comment: You could schedule the job with an immediate trigger. http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.0/org/quartz/TriggerUtils.html#makeImmediateTrigger%28int,%20long%29

Answer (score 1):

You can could spawn a new thread (preferably via a `java.util.Executor` or a Spring `TaskExecutor`) to perform the subsidiary task. Spring's transaction synchronization works using non-inheritable ThreadLocal variables, so a new thread will not participate in the current transaction.

Alternatively, and perhaps more elegantly, you can specify an explicit transaction isolation level around the subsidiary task, something like:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void doTheThing() { /.../ }
```

This will suspend the existing transaction for the duration of that method, although you'd still need to be careful with runtime exceptions not bubbling up into your main transaction boundary.

Regards your second question, locking and synchronisation in a cluster is a very complex topic, and not one I can really answer with the information you've given. I suggest opening a new question for this, and elaborate your requirements.